# Chromedrive crashes every time I run the script file in python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to run a python script to print all results from a simple google search. The first time when I run this code, it works, but only once. This makes no sense and I don't have a logical explanation for this. I have no errors. Chrome is up to date and Chromedriver as well, using Python3.6.

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

search_term = "kid"
url = "https://www.google.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\amzar\\Desktop\\pyscripts\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
search_box.send_keys(search_term)
search_box.submit()
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3//a")

results = []
    for link in links:
    hr = link.get_attribute("href")
    print(hr)
    results.append(hr)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work after the first time? What does it do?

Comment: try leaving out  ".exe" from the string in the driver = webdriver.Chrome("...") line

Comment: Is not working if I remove `exe`. It does nothing, just open testing window and crashes.